# How to increase cell height in ComplexHeatmap?

Tags: r, rstudio, heatmap

I have used the code below for creating a heatmap for my DEG genes using `Heatmap ()` (**library("ComplexHeatmap"**)).

My problem is this that **the cell heights are very small** and the **row names** (88 gene IDs) are not clearly observable.

I have increased the row names font and row dend size, but it did not work for me.

NOTE: I could not use "cell_fun" function!

~ Thank you in advance

This is my Code:

```
library(gplots)
library("ComplexHeatmap")
library(dendextend)
library("RColorBrewer")
filename <- "male-female-88-TMMb.matrix"
my_data <- read.table(filename, sep='\t', quote='', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
row.names(my_data) <- my_data$samples
my_data <- my_data[, -1]
my_data <- my_data/rowSums(my_data)

row.scaled.expr <- as.matrix(my_data) 

row.names(my_data) <- my_data$samples
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data) 
my_data <- my_data[, -1]

data.prop <- my_data/rowSums(my_data)

mycol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10, "RdYlBu"))(256)

.hist = anno_histogram(row.scaled.expr, gp = gpar(fill = "olivedrab3"))

.density = anno_density(row.scaled.expr, type = "line", gp = gpar(col = "blue"))

ha_mix_top = HeatmapAnnotation(hist = .hist, density = .density)

.violin = anno_density(row.scaled.expr, type = "violin", 
                           gp = gpar(fill = "darkorchid4"), which = "row")

ha_mix_right = HeatmapAnnotation (violin = .violin,
                                  which = "row", width = unit(4.5, "cm"))

Heatmap (as.matrix(data.prop), km = 2, name = "TMM", col = mycol,
         column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8.5),
         row_names_side = "left",
         row_dend_side = "left",
         clustering_method_columns = "ward.D",
         clustering_method_rows = "ward.D",
         column_dend_side = c("bottom"),
         column_dend_height = unit(6, "mm"),
         row_dend_width = unit(3.6, "cm"),
         row_dend_gp = gpar (15),
         gap = unit(1, "mm"),
         row_title_gp = gpar(col = c("red2", "blue4"), font = 2:2),
         row_names_gp = gpar(col = c("red2", "blue4"), fontsize = c(8.4, 8.6)),
         rect_gp = gpar(col = "gray12", lty = 1, lwd = 0.2),
         top_annotation = ha_mix_top, 
         top_annotation_height = unit(3, "cm")) + ha_mix_right
```

head of my "data.prop" file :

> head(data.prop)

```
                          F1         F2        F3         M1          M2
DN107669_c1_g2_i1 0.68965517 0.05627846 0.2540664 0.00000000 0.000000000
DN101742_c5_g1_i2 0.27241615 0.20739220 0.5140315 0.00000000 0.006160164
DN107731_c4_g1_i4 0.17056856 0.56187291 0.2675585 0.00000000 0.000000000
DN108762_c0_g1_i9 0.00000000 0.85127479 0.1487252 0.00000000 0.000000000
DN111305_c2_g4_i1 0.08341354 0.32996471 0.5731473 0.01347449 0.000000000
DN101817_c3_g1_i3 0.11783015 0.51504372 0.2967245 0.01081962 0.050096339
                           M3
DN107669_c1_g2_i1 0.000000000
DN101742_c5_g1_i2 0.000000000
DN107731_c4_g1_i4 0.000000000
DN108762_c0_g1_i9 0.000000000
DN111305_c2_g4_i1 0.000000000
DN101817_c3_g1_i3 0.009485697
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make your data available, or give some code to make something similar that illustrates the problem? Like is it just a 6column 88 row data frame with those 6 names F1,2,3 and M1,2,3?

Comment: Where does the ComplexHeatmap package come from?

Comment: Ah right, BioConductor. What other packages does this code use? RColorBrewer, grid... where does `row.scaled.expr` come from?

Comment: Hi, there is a cell_fun in this site [http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s2.single_heatmap.html]. But I can not use it. It seems that with it we can manipulate each (all) cells in the heatmap. Would you please have a look at it and tell me how to increase the size of all cells ?

Comment: http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s2.single_heatmap.html

Comment: You need to make your code so that anyone can run it, and maybe include a screenshot of what you get. At the moment nobody can see what you are seeing because your code doesn't run.

Comment: Hi, As I have provide my script of R here, do you mean that I must provide my raw "male-female-88-TMMb.matrix" file here? How I can upload it ? or upload any image in the "Comments" section ?

Comment: You've still not said where `row.scaled.expr` comes from. I can make a data frame to test it easily enough.

Comment: Hi,  Spacedman. Yes, sorry about that. now I have edited my code so you can check it for row.scaled.expr. Thanks

Comment: You can only make the labels bigger by making the figure bigger. If you have 88 rows and want to show all 88 labels then what else can you do?

Comment: How to "make the figure bigger" ?

Comment: Get a bigger monitor? Print it on bigger paper? What's limiting the size of the figure now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I have recieved from Zuguang Gu the creator of ComplexHeatmap (Heatmap()):

> How do you save the image into a file? Using `pdf()` function or click
>   "save" or "export" in Rstudio?
>
> If you use `pdf()`, you can set the size of the plot by `width` and
>   `height` argument.
>
> If you directly save the image in Rstudio, there must be some place
>   that you can adjust the size of the pdf file.

I have used his guidance in *Rstudio* and it solved the problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `heatmap_height` parameter:

> `heatmap_width` and `heatmap_height` control the width/height of the **complete heatmap including all heatmap components (excluding the legends)**

eg:

```
Heatmap(mat, ..., heatmap_height = unit(1, "cm")*nrow(mat))
```